# Vb.net sending email time out error

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

i'm having a problem sending an email via vb.net SMTP program
everything was working at home very smoothly  but when i came to use it in here at work (my company blocks youtube, facebook , ...etc) it didn't work and get an error of time out .
is it possible that my company blocked port 25 and different smtp ports??
what are other possibilities for that error 
thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to ask your company's IT department what SMTP server you can use.

Comment: Yeah, port 25 is commonly blocked. Try 587

Comment: i tried both  ....same result